# Is it possible to do a "where <property> in <set>" query with Breeze js

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, breeze

Is it possible to do an "IN" query with Breeze?

I am using Entity Framework and I have a Order object and it has a UserId property:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    // ... other properties

}
```

I have a controller that will return Orders in an IQueryable:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Order> Orders()
{
    return Db.Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id);
}
```

Where 'Db' is my EF context. I would like to get orders where the UserId property is in a set of user Ids, i.e. [1,4,78] or any other set.

I can't work out if it's possible and if so how? i.e:

```
var userIds = [1,4,78];

breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Orders")
    .using(this.manager)
    //.where("userId", "any", userIds) // this isn't right
    .execute()
    .then( 
       // ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
    var userIds = [1, 4, 78];

    var predicate = breeze.Predicate("userId", "==", userIds[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < userIds.length; i++) {
        var userId = userIds[i];
        predicate = predicate.or(breeze.Predicate("userId", "==", userId));
    }

    breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Orders")
        .using(this.manager)
        .where(predicate)
        .execute();
```

Comment: Heh! I feel silly that I didn't think to try it like that I was stuck looking for an "IN" operator. This works like a charm with the minor amend that it's breeze.Predicate.create()

Comment: We do wish that OData query syntax supported an "in" clause; it doesn't